# Why does 'iterator_to_array' give different results than foreach?

Tags: php, generator

Suppose I have the following recursive function to turn an array into a Generator:

```php
function traverse(array $items): Generator {
    if (!empty($items)) {
        yield $items[0];

        array_shift($items);
        yield from traverse($items);
    }
}
```

Running this function and iterating over the Generator through a `foreach` gives the expected result:

```php
$values = traverse(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']);

foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo $value;
}

// 'abcde' is echoed
```

However, when I use the built-in function `iterator_to_array()`, I get the following result:

```php
$values = iterator_to_array(traverse(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']));

foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo $value;
}

// Only 'e' is echoed
```

I would expect both pieces of code to behave identically, yet they don't. Why is their behavior different?

I am running this on PHP 8.1.

Comment: What happens if you change the function to iterative instead of recursive?

Comment: @Barmar Changing the function to an iterative implementation gives the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php#control-structures.yield.from):

> **yield from does not reset the keys**. It preserves the keys returned by the Traversable object, or array. Thus some values may share a common key with another yield or yield from, which, upon insertion into an array, will overwrite former values with that key.
>
> A common case where this matters is iterator_to_array() returning a keyed array by default, leading to possibly unexpected results. iterator_to_array() has a second parameter use_keys which can be set to false to collect all the values while ignoring the keys returned by the Generator.

Your generator is returning an item with the same key each time (because they are reset after the `array_shift` call), so `iterator_to_array` is overwriting each item with the following one. This is why you're only seeing the final element being returned.

If you pass the `use_keys` argument to the function as *false*, you'll get the desired behaviour, e.g.

```
$values = iterator_to_array(traverse(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']), false);
```

See https://3v4l.org/jWbt4

Comment: And if you change the first snippet to use `foreach ($values as $key => $value)` and print `$key`, you would see this in action.

Comment: @Barmar Ooh yes, nice. Lovely to see the same key coming out of a foreach loop every time https://3v4l.org/bdYkV